# Why does put the comma before trapping?

Tags: grammar

When an insect lands on one of them, the leaf snaps shut***,***trapping the creature inside like a prisoner behind bars.

Why does put the comma before trapping?

Comment: Who wrote this sentence?  Please tell us the source of the quote.  What do you think is the purpose of commas?  Have you studied commas in English writing?

Comment: I looked for the usage of the comma, but I did not find any rules to explain the comma in this sentence. This is why I asked here.

Comment: thank you, but please provide extra details!  Who wrote this sentence?

Comment: The leaf snaps shut. The effect of this is to trap the insect. The comma marks a natural pause in the sentence.

Comment: Ah! [venus fly traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_flytrap)!

Comment: I wish that I could edit the question title. The original title was, "Why ***does put*** the comma before trapping?" However, I am no longer allowed to edit questions on this website. I want to change "***does put***" to "***do we put***". The result would be: Why ***do we put*** the comma before trapping?"

Answer (score -1):

Your original sentence was,

> When an insect lands on one of them, the leaf snaps shut, trapping the creature inside like a prisoner behind bars.

You asked why there was a comma.

When people recite English out-loud, they breathe in and out of their lungs. The commas show where people transition between breathing in or breathing out.

> 1. When an insect lands on one of them (BREATHING-OUT)
> 2. pause
> 3. The leaf snaps shut (BREATHING-IN)
> 4. pause
> 5. trapping the creature inside (BREATHING-OUT)
> 6. pause
> 7. like a prisoner behind bars. (BREATHING-IN)

It is standard practice to insert a comma anytime that people pause in their breathing. periods dots or full-stops are also used when people pause in their breathing.

The original sentence can be re-written as two separate sentences:

> When an insect lands on one of the leaves, the leaf snaps shut.
> The leaf traps the creature inside like a prisoner behind bars.

The presence of commas (**,**) within a sentence almost always indicates that the sentence can re-written as the concatenation of two or more simpler sentences.

Comment: A comma often coincides with a pause, but this rule is not reliable.  One would not write a comma if the reason for the pause is to think of the best word.  Conversely, a comma can help clarify sentence structure even if a pause is unlikely.